# What does @ in `-rw-r--r--@` mean in the `ls -l` output?

Tags: bash, macos, ls

I was examining output of `ls -l` in by bash completion folder on Mac OS X

```
$ ls -alrth /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-machine* 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 abhimskywalker  staff   1.4K Jun 13 19:04 /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-machine-prompt.bash
-rw-r--r--@ 1 abhimskywalker  staff   1.5K Jun 13 19:36 /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-machine-wrapper.bash
-rw-r--r--@ 1 abhimskywalker  staff   6.8K Jun 13 19:37 /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-machine.bash
```

I could not understand what does this `@` mean in `-rw-r--r--@`?

Comment: probably has an ACL on it or something.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It indicates that the file has [extended attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes). You can use the xattr command-line utility to view and modify them:

```
xattr -l file # lists the names of all xattrs.
xattr -w attr_name attr_value file # sets xattr attr_name to attr_value.
xattr -d attr_name file # deletes xattr attr_name.
xattr -c file # deletes all xattrs.
xattr -h # prints help
```

You can also use `ls -l@` to see more information about those extended attributes.

From the osx `ls` man page:

> The Long Format
>   **If the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions field printed by the -l option is followed by an @ character**. Otherwise, if the file or directory has extended security information, the permissions field printed by the -l option is followed by a + character.

And

> -@      Display extended attribute keys and sizes in long (-l) output.

Comment: I added my answer to yours to make it more complete. Feel free to roll it back if you don't want it there though.

Comment: As you said, I find the answer more complete too so I'll keep your changes. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah... My bad, I missed this in the man page. Thanks!
I saw the `-@` option for extended attribute, but couldn't find the "Long format" os x man page description for `@`.